# Integral of the log of the absolute value over a complex disc

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, logarithms, contour-integration

Stuck on this integration problem, it’s probably really obvious. Talk to me like someone who’s taken complex analysis but forgets the rules. Advisor said something about the Cauchy Integral Formula, but I’m not sure how that applies.

$U(z)= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int^{2 \pi} \log \frac{1}{|z - a - r e ^{i \theta}|} d \theta$

The given solution is $\log \frac{1}{r}$ for $|z - a| \leq r$ and $\log \frac{1}{|z - a|}$ for $|z - a| \geq r$.  My first obvious step was to make the substitution $w = z - a$ so the new problem is $U(w)= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int^{2 \pi} \log \frac{1}{|w - r e ^{i \theta}|} d \theta$

Case 1: $|w| > r$. Write the function $h(\zeta)= \log\frac{1}{|w - \zeta|}$.  h is harmonic on the disc $D(0, r + \epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon > 0$, so the Mean Value Property for harmonic functions says $h(0)= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} \log \frac{1}{|w - r e ^{i \theta}|} d \theta$.  Thus $U(w)=h(0)=\log \frac{1}{|w|} = \log \frac{1}{|z - a|}$.

Case 2: $|w| \leq r$. In this case, the function $h(\zeta)=\log \frac{1}{|w − \zeta|}$ is not harmonic in the interior of the disc (it has a pole where $\zeta = w$), so the Mean Value Property does not apply. I can't figure out case 2, but I'm still working on it.

(Edit to fix the problem in case 1.)

Comment: The trick for case $2$ is to show that for $|y| \le 1, \int_0^{2\pi}\log|y-e^{i\theta}|d\theta=0$ which (for example) follows for $|y|<1$ from the Jensen formula applied to $f(w)=w-y$ and by continuity (dominated convergence theorem) for $|y|=1$ (this one is also a classic real trigonometric integral that can be shown to be zero directly by the doubling trick); forcing out a $\log 1/r$ in the integral in case $2$ leads precisely to the above zero integral with $y=w/r$ as in this case $|y| \le 1$, so indeed the original integral is $\log 1/r$